# Updating Okta User profile

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am using Okta C# sdk for development. I have created some custom user profile attributes in the Okta. I am able to create user and save values in custom attributes.
But as I saw that when you update profile data you have to provide all the details again. If you provide specific attributes value then sets null for other attributes. So how can I update only one or two attributes so that other should not change.

Answer (score 3):

Dinesh.
You can use a POST /users/:id if you want to make a partial update. **Make sure not to use a PUT** for this operation else you will wipe out the remaining values that are not in the Request